Schedule Firebase Functions in Python
I'm trying to schedule this function to run every week on Monday at 00:05 AM.
But it doesn't run at that time. Using @scheduler_fn.on_schedule has no effect on my function.
@https_fn.on_request()
@scheduler_fn.on_schedule(
    schedule="5 0 * * 0",
    timezone=scheduler_fn.Timezone("Europe/Bucharest")
)
def scheduleFunction(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:


I am not familiar with firebase's python SDK, it seems you are trying to add both annotation to the same function, will it really work? I think normally you should declare two functions for each, because from the document the parameter for schedule function is in this type scheduler_fn.ScheduledEvent, not requests. If it is working, I think you can find the deployed function in GCP's Cloud Scheduler

According to the official documentation regarding writing a scheduled function using Cloud Functions 2nd gen, you should only add a single annotation, which is @scheduler_fn. So assuming that you already added the import from firebase_functions import scheduler_fn, the code should look like this:
from firebase_functions import scheduler_fn

@scheduler_fn.on_schedule(
    schedule="every monday 00:05",
    timezone=scheduler_fn.Timezone("Europe/Bucharest")
)

While the AppEngine syntax for scheduling the function every week, on Monday that exists in your code might work, please note that it's easier to use every monday 00:05.
Going forward, according to the same docs, the argument that should be passed to the scheduleFunction function should be of type ScheduledEvent and not of type Request, as you currently pass.

Hey Cosmin. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
